# Spring Boot redundant application properties in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, properties, yaml

I am trying to use necessary fields and remove unnecessary or redundant fields in my `application.yml`, but there are some properties that seem to be duplicate or same features.

Here is an example features below.

**1.** I think I should use dialect property, but which one should I use (`jpa.properties.dialect` or `jpa.database-platform`) or both?

**2.** As far as I see from [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html), it seems optional to use `jpa.database` property. But not sure if I can omit `jpa.database` and `jpa.properties.dialect` properties both. Any idea for this?

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:${DB_NAME};DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: 
  jpa:
    properties:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect         // ???
    database: h2                                       // ???
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect // ???
```

Comment: Does anybody else have never used these features?

Comment: Instead of testing everything one by one with some combinations, I would generally prefer to know the meaning of them.

Comment: REFERENCE: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data

Comment: Please Referemce `Accessing Data with JPA` (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) , you can find source, you can find `pom.xml` only assign database `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>` , then `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` will know you are using h2 database. no more config. Only if your settings are different from the default ones, you need to add the settings manually.

Comment: I already add it to my pom.xml, but trying to understand if I have to use these annotations and what is the purpose of using them. If you have any idea, could you clarify me?

Comment: And as far as I know, dialect property is needed and important

Comment: unzip `Accessing Data with JPA` example, goto gs-accessing-data-jpa-main, goto sub dir `complete` , you can run, `mvn spring-boot:run` , and you can find therre are no `application.properties` file existing. But it can running normally. It means spring-boot data jpa starter find database dependency (H2) and use default value.